# I'm having trouble with this exercise on hacker rank please look

Tags: javascript, parsing, installation, int

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001

Here is the problem I'm confused what the parseInt readline statement 
and also the the var n statement mainly..

when i run my code it seems to count up to ten twice probably a simple problem just not seeing it and was hoping I could get it explained so I can keep working on project euler problems

Thanks

```
    function main() {
     var t = parseInt(readLine());
     var sum = 0; 
     var arr = []; 

    for(var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        var n = parseInt(readLine());
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0){
                arr.push(i);
                sum += i; 
            };
        console.log(arr);
    };

}
```

Comment: Its the problem statement for us or __you__?

Comment: Please update the name of your question to better describe the specific question you have.

Comment: With two small modifications, this code will pass the test. As you are trying to learn I won't tell you what to change but will make two comments that might point you in the right direction. Firstly, you need to log to the console the *sum* of the numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5. Also you are only interested in the sum of the numbers from 0 to the current value of n, you don't care about the previous line

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not following exactly what is your question.

The parseInt is a javascript function. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

The readLine() function is defined for you, it will give you "the next line" that was captured from standard in. 
All (or most) of the hackerrank problems offer the input for the problem thru standard-in and expect the result from standard-out.  So for this problem, hackerrank has created this boilerplate code for reading that input.

```
   process.stdin.on('end', function () {
      input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
      main();    
   });
```

There is filling the `input_stdin_array` array that is used on the readLine() function.

And about the

> when i run my code it seems to count up to ten twice

The problem mentions:

> First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.

So you are printing the array T times (for the default test case is 2), so that why you probably see the "up to ten 2 times"

I hope this helped, and probably you could start with a couple of the https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/tutorials/30-days-of-code challenge so you get a better grasp of how to work on the problems.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array after the first for loop. You are using the same array for every test case, even though it still contains numbers from the previous test cases. Same for the sum.

```
for(var a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++) {
  var arr = [];
  var sum = 0;
```